# tkinter setting default checkbox to being checked returns value as "checked"

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code:

```
master = Tk()  
var1 = IntVar(master) 
var1.set(1) 
Checkbutton(master, text = 'check', variable = var1)
Button(text = 'submit', command = master.quit') 
check = var1.get()
```

It sets the default to being checked, but even when I uncheck it on the GUI and hit submit, the value of check is still 1.

Why is the action of unchecking the checkbox not being registered?

Comment: This code won't run. If you're going to post code, it needs to be runnable code that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First off the code yo have shown us will not work for a few reason.

You have a `'` just after `master.quit` you also are trying to create a button without assigning it to a window or frame. You have not  used `pack()`, `grid()` or `place()` to place the widgets into a window. You do not need to assign the value of master inside if `IntVar()`.

Most likely the reason you think the value of `IntVar()` is not changing is because you have assigned the value of `IntVar()` to the variable `check` when the program is instantiated.

With the code you have shown us nothing is changing or updating the value of `check`.

Instead you should use something that can be called on to check the current value of `var1` like a function.

Here is a simple program that shows what happens each time you check or uncheck the box.

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()  
var1 = tk.IntVar() 
var1.set(1) 

tk.Checkbutton(master, text = 'check', variable = var1).pack()

def print_var1():
    print(var1.get())

tk.Button(master, text = "Print Var1", command = print_var1).pack()
tk.Button(master, text = 'Close', command = lambda: master.destroy()).pack() 

master.mainloop()
```